# Unable to get Internet in Xubuntu while using USb 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adapter, though it works fine in Windows 7

Tags: networking, usb, xubuntu, ethernet

I am new to Linux. I recently installed Xubuntu. My computer is dual-booted with Windows 7 and Xubuntu running in the same machine. It works fine in every way. The internet in Xubuntu also worked fine. However, a few days back, due to a lightning strike, the internet port in the rear side of my CPU got damaged. The ethernet cable was operational, but due to internet port damage, I lost my internet connection.

I bought a usb 2.0 10/100M ethernet adapter (**Kontron DM9601 fast ethernet adapter**) and plugged the ethernet LAN cable into it. This adapter was then plugged into a USB port. After installing the right drivers and re-configuring the IP Addresses (the ones which were there before the port damage) in Windows 7, the internet seems to have returned and the Internet works well in Windows 7. However, when I restarted the machine and opened Xubuntu, there was disappointment ahead. Even when the adapter was plugged in, there was no internet connection in Xubuntu. I configured VPN > Created a new Ethernet Connection > Deleted the existing but unusable Ethernet Connection > Set the Mac Address > Set the IP Address, netmask, Gateway, DNS Server under IPv4 Settings> Saved and closed the Network Connections box.

However, even with all these efforts and many more, I am still unable to set up my Internet Connection in Xubuntu. It shows

> Disconnected : you are now offline.

---

I ran the terminal and executed

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Yes chili, the third bus device is my existing usb to ethernet adapter. The details of my usb to ethernet adapter as listed above (though it is the bus) is:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
```

I hope this is the info you asked for, chili555. Still no internet connection in Xubuntu.

---

I ran

> sudo modprobe dm9601

in the terminal. The output just asked for my password and nothing else changed.

Code:

```
[sudo] password for subhankar:
```

Next I typed

> ifconfig

The output was

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:d1:8b:86  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe400000-fe420000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:01:00:9c:34
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:1ff:fe00:9c34/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3106 (3.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17617 (17.6 KB)  TX bytes:17617 (17.6 KB)
```

There is still no internet in Xubuntu. One thing I would like to mention is that, there is a feeble connection for a few seconds and then I am back to disconnected. The connection lasts for so short time that I cannot open any website with it.

Anyway, thanks for the reply, chili. Any further suggestion is welcome.

---

You may be right, chili. I was also getting a feeling that my 2 ethernet connections eth0 and eth2 were clashing against each other. But, I am at a loss on how to resolve this possible conflict.

On opening my Network Connections, both eth0 and eth2 are listed, but they are grayed out. Both of them are displayed as disconnected.

I opened the terminal and entered

> lsmod

The output is a huge one. I am listing the output below.

Code:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
rfcomm                 61440  4
bluetooth             430080  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            20480  1
sr9700                 16384  0
dm9601                 16384  0
usbnet                 40960  2 dm9601,sr9700
mii                    16384  3 dm9601,sr9700,usbnet
snd_hda_codec_realtek    69632  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          32768  6 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         122880  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94208  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
gpio_ich               16384  0 
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             139264  0 
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
kvm                   413696  1 kvm_intel
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28672  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
aesni_intel            20480  0
snd                    69632  22 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
aes_i586               20480  1 aesni_intel
xts                    16384  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  2 lrw,xts
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 16384  1 ablk_helper
i915                  925696  3 
serio_raw              16384  0 
video                  20480  1 i915
lpc_ich                20480  0 
drm_kms_helper        114688  1 i915
shpchp                 32768  0 
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
drm                   286720  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 20480  0 
mei                    77824  1 mei_me
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
8250_fintek            16384  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  1 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     16384  0 
parport                40960  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 49152  0 
hid                    98304  2 hid_generic,usbhid
e1000e                212992  0 
psmouse               102400  0 
ahci                   32768  3 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
```

I can't figure out what does most of these stuff mean, but from the looks of it, I recognize dm9601 which has some link with my usb to ethernet connection. There are 3 entries related to dm9601 at the beginning of lsmod list. I am relisting them below for your ready perusal.

Code:

```
dm9601                 16384  0
usbnet                 40960  2 dm9601,sr9700
mii                    16384  3 dm9601,sr9700,usbnet
```

Thanks for your quick reply, chili. It was too late at night when I edited the previous post, that's why I couldnot reply to you earlier. I am sorry for that. Hope this result clears some clouds of obscurity. No internet in Xubuntu yet. Thanks.

---

How do I install the drivers  for DM9601 ethernet adapter in Xubuntu? I firmly think that this is most likely a driver problem. I received a mini-disk during purchase of the usb-to-ethernet adapter with driver files to be installed in linux. However, I can't figure out 'How to do it!!!'. Is there anyone who can offer an easy step-by-step procedure for installation of DM9601 driver in Xubuntu? I have listed the output of important commands above. If someone needs any more info, I shall gladly provide it. It is really hopeless to work without internet in Xubuntu. Installation of some softwares are very difficult without net due to dependencies and stuff. Thanks.

Comment: What is the adapter's model?

Comment: My model is USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor . In Windows, the driver by which I successfully installed the Adapter is RD9700 USB 2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any more information that I need to reveal,Alexiy? I have been struggling a lot. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lsusb`. Pick out your ethernet adapter and edit your question to add the details.

Comment: I opened a terminal and ran lsusb. Bus 001 Device 005 listed the ethernet adapter. (I have written it in details below). However it doesnot mention that it is a USB to Ethernet adapter. I am a bit skeptical about this. Anybody out there with a solution? What to do after this?

Answer (score 1):

Your device is covered by the module *dm9601*. Please load it:

```
sudo modprobe dm9601
```

Is an interface, ideally eth1, created?

```
ifconfig
```

When you click the Network Manager icon, does it show an available ethernet connection?

I suspect that your previous settings will all need to be deleted.

If you have an eth0, it appears that the internal ethernet is (sort of) working. I suggest we find out its driver and blacklist it so the two interfaces don't potentially conflict. Please edit your question to add the full result of:

```
lsmod
```

Depending upon your response, I will further edit this answer to propose a solution.

Comment: Yes, eth0 and eth2 are created. I believe, eth2 is the actual ethernet connection because, when I unplug my adapter from the USB port, eth2 disappears from ifconfig list, but eth0 and lo stays right there. On replugging the adapter, eth2 is listed back in ifconfig. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my further edit above in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this same issue on Ubuntu 15.10. So far I have managed to understand it is a driver related issue, at least for my ethernet adapter.

Output of status commands:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
~$ ifconfig
enx00e04c534458 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:53:44:58  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6902 (6.9 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:164248 (164.2 KB)  TX bytes:164248 (164.2 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:02:b5:3f:40:3a  
      inet addr:192.168.1.19  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::1202:b5ff:fe3f:403a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4834 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2503075 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:730088 (730.0 KB)
~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
qf9700                 20480  0
sr9700                 16384  0
dm9601                 16384  0
usbnet                 40960  3 dm9601,qf9700,sr9700
mii                    16384  4 dm9601,qf9700,sr9700,usbnet
~$ modinfo dm9601
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 ethernet devices
author:         Peter Korsgaard <jacmet@sunsite.dk>
srcversion:     8B2420E93E78CEA9AB0E3DA
alias:          usb:v0A46p1269d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p0269d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9622d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9621d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9620d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE6p9700d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE6p8101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A47p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p8515d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p0268d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p6688d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbnet,mii
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        54:4E:45:C0:BD:E6:F7:84:07:7A:BC:A3:DE:58:E4:8F:B5:25:EE:14
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
~$  modinfo sr9700
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/sr9700.ko
license:        GPL
description:    SR9700 one chip USB 1.1 USB to Ethernet device from http://www.corechip-sz.com/
author:         liujl <liujunliang_ljl@163.com>
srcversion:     FC7BD07740E01F718979223
alias:          usb:v0FE6p9700d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbnet,mii
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        54:4E:45:C0:BD:E6:F7:84:07:7A:BC:A3:DE:58:E4:8F:B5:25:EE:14
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

The problem is that the chip in the adapter is supposed to work with the dm9601 driver, but the actual manufacturer is CoreChip. So the correct driver would be the sr9700.

Another strange thing is that the interface the driver creates is called `enx00e04c534458` (the number is also the MAC address of the adapter), which is different than any `ethX` for native ethernet ports.

The next thing is to force Ubuntu to use the specific driver and test the solution. I will edit the answer when I get more information.

I know this is not the solution, but hope this information helps in solving the issue.

Comment: Well, I tried to install the sr9700 driver in xubuntu by opening a terminal and typing, **sudo modprobe sr9700**. Still, it is of no aid. There is still the persisting transient connection that doesnot open any sites and immediately leaps back to disconnection. Anyways, thanks very much for your suggestion. I have almost given up hope. Your answer after a long time is highly appreciated.